# DirectX 9 cannot change resolution

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx, directx-9

I'm trying to change the window resolution like this:

```
pp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
pp.Windowed = true;
pp.BackBufferWidth = s.x;
pp.BackBufferHeight = s.y;
pp.BackBufferCount = 1;
pp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = true;
pp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
pp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_FLIP;
pp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_R5G6B5;
m_pDevice->Reset(&pp);
```

Previously I resize window like this:

```
SetWindowPos(g_Window, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 521, 300, SWP_NOMOVE);
```

But reset always returns `INVALID_CALL`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you didn't dispose all you resources (vertex buffer, texture, ...)